# Yii2 with Spin.js to show activity after form submitted

Tags: spinner, yii2, spin.js

I have been trying to use spin.js with Yii2 to show activity after submitting a form. The wait time can be as long as 5 seconds so therefore I need to show that the site is working.

I am able to display the spinner with:

```
<?= Spinner::widget() ?>
```

I would like to use the widget with DOM  to start and turn it off on page load.
My code is as below:

```
    spinr = {
        "start": function() {
            var target = $("body")[0];
            return "<?= Spinner::widget() ?>".(target);
        },
        "stop": function(spinner) {
            spinner.stop();
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Once the DOM is loaded, start spinning
        spinner = spinr.start();
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
        // Once the page is fully loaded, stop spinning
        spinr.stop(spinner);
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does changing the last line of the `start` function to `return new Spinner({}).(target);` and manually including the js file work?

Comment: With a bit of fiddling that works.  I fixed with `return new Spinner().spin(target);`  However I want to use the existing Yii2 **Spinner::widget** to perform the action.